# Get Mac notification settings in Electron

Tags: macos, electron

Is there a convenient way to get the Mac system notification settings in Electron? (eg. 'Play Sound for notifications')
The current lib I found can get 'getDoNotDisturb' but didn't find an API to check the notification settings.